# Magento: Enable or Disable a module in code

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a Module that loads a whole bunch of Observers for a specific task on one theme. I've setup a mobile theme that doesn't need this specific module. How do I disable the module for that theme ?
I read the answers on [Magento, how to disable module programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520634/magento-how-to-disable-module-programmatically) that isn't really helpful for my case because I don't have any controllers in the module.

I am checking the Package name `if (Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getPackageName() == 'package') return true;` but this doesn't work for the observed `core_collection_abstract_load_after`, it just crashes. So I want to not load anything at all to spare some processing time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot disable magento modules inside from magento, because they are already loaded when the observer-system is initialized.

What you can do is to disable your observers:

```
Mage::getConfig()->setNode('frontend/events/yourEventName/observers/yourObserverName/type', 'disabled');
```

This can be done in every event, especially in your `core_collection_abstract_load_after`

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I think I will modify the original module