# magento disable modules script

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am doing some testing on a new feature, however, there is a conflict with a module that we have running. I have to disable the module in the xml file of the etc folder(set active to false) to do testing, but turn it on again to check whether compatibility is fixed. This is quite a nuisance and I was wondering if there is a script that can turn it off and on when I run it.

This is not the first time i have run into the issue.

I am somewhat new to magento so I just want to make sure I am doing things correctly. Here is what I threw together so far, but it probably needs corrections, and I'm not sure what to put in some spots. This is to get the module disabled.

```
<?php
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("myExt.xml");

$root=$dom->documentElement; 

$modules=$root->getElementsByTagName('module');


foreach ($modules as $module) {
    $active=$module->getElementsByTagName('active')//Not sure how to end this line
    $active='false'; //This is probably incorrect

}
$dom->save('myExt.xml');
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From your code it looks like you just want to write a script to disable the module whenever you run the script. Is that true, or do you want a script that can run within Magento, specifically, to disable the module under certain circumstances?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520634/magento-how-to-disable-module-programmatically (This question may be a duplicate of that question, but only if OP wants to do it on the fly during requests.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider just using xmllint, which can do simple xml edits more trivially than writing a php program to do it:

```
{
    echo 'cd //active'
    echo 'set false'
    echo 'save'
} | xmllint --shell app/etc/modules/YourModule.xml
```

You could even make this into a simple shell function:

```
##
# Toggle Magento module active or inactive
magetogmod() {
    {
        echo 'cd //active'
        echo "set $1" # First argument. Should be 'true' or 'false'.
        echo 'save'
    } | xmllint --shell "app/etc/modules/$2.xml" # 2nd arg. Should be the filename without '.xml'
}

# Shortcuts so you don't have to type "true" and "false" all the time:

##
# Disable Magento module
magedismod() { magetogmod false "$1"; }

##
# Enable Magento module
mageenmod() { magetogmod true "$1"; }
```

Then you will need to clear cache if you have config cache turned on.

Comment: Please note that if the configuration cache is enabled your solution won't work. Anyway, cool answer!

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand each part of this as I am unfamiliar with xmllint. Is the $1 related to the $1 that you are passing in (which is either set to true or false). If this is so, should the line in the function be echo "set {$1}";

Comment: I have a few different modules to disable so I wanted to write a script to run in or out of magento that could do it for me. Within magento would be best so that I don't have to keep pushing to my git repository of the staging server.

Comment: @Speed It's not exactly possible to do it in Magento, as the module configs are loaded before any events are fired. See the link in my comment to your question. But you could create a `ZZZ_moduleenabler.xml` in app/etc/modules that is in `.gitignore` and use it to enable/disable modules.

Comment: @Speed edited to hopefully make things clearer. Like php, shell variables are expanded with a dollar sign. Unlike php, you can't wrap the entire expression with curly braces (at least not `{$x}`). (An earlier edition of this answer had mistakenly used "$1" for the second parameter as well.)

Comment: @kojiro I think it should be possible because on the initial load, I can have all the configs load, then I can run this php script that will turn of these handful of extensions (by turn off, I mean completed disable by turning active to false in the etc/modules), and then i can reload which will now fire only the enabled configs. I may be mistaken in thinking this is how it works, like I said, I am new to magento and I will defer to someone who actually knows about how the system works. Thank you for the responses. I am hoping to do it without xmllint, if possible.